# PHP: Doing while loop if "if" statement is true

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to show only those events, which are in current date or in future. To show events I have such code:

```
<?php 
    $wp_query = new WP_Query();
    global $more;
    // set $more to 0 in order to only get the first part of the post
    $more = 0; 
    $wp_query->query( array( 'post_type' => 'events', 'posts_per_page' => 7, 'paged' => $paged, 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC') );

    while ( ($wp_query->have_posts()) ): $wp_query->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'content', 'event' );
    endwhile;
?>
```

I tried to add "IF statement" to compare event start date with current date, but it doesn't seem to work. I have tried a lots of versions, but this one I think should work:

```
 $wp_query->query( array( 'post_type' => 'events', 'posts_per_page' => 7, 'paged' => $paged, 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC') );
 $OstartDate = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_event_start', TRUE);
 $today = date('d.m.Y');
 while ( ($wp_query->have_posts()) && ($OstarDate < $today) ): 
      $wp_query->the_post();
```

Comment: Did you try using some sort of date constraint in the query? That seems a much better way to do this, the big problem with your current approach is the fact that you may get fewer than seven on your page. Also, I don't think you're comparing the dates properly. Are you sire you're actually doing the comparison you meant to do there? (E.g. the string "12/1/2013" will evaluate as less than than 2/1/2013 in a text  comparison)

Answer (score 0):

From the `second one` you should try,

```
$OstartDate=get_post_meta($post->ID,'_event_start',TRUE);//check it will return a number
if(time() > $OstartDate)
{
   while ($wp_query->have_posts()):
      $wp_query->the_post();
   .....
}
```

[a7-simple-events](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/a7-simple-events/trunk/a7-simple-events.php) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the posts with postmeta using meta_query

```
$today = date('d.m.Y');
 $args=array( 'post_type' => 'events', 'posts_per_page' => 7, 'paged' => $paged, 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC', 'meta_query'            => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_event_start',
            'value' => $today,
            'type' => 'date',
            'compare' => '<'
        )
    )) ;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

 while ( ($wp_query->have_posts())  ): 
      $wp_query->the_post();
      endwhile;
```